# This code use switch-case and if else if else which is better?

Tags: ios, objective-c

code

```
if ([@[@1,@2,@3] containsObject:@(section)]) {
    return 10;
}else if ([@[@0,@4] containsObject:@(section)]) {
    return 15;
}else {
    return 0;
}
```

&&

```
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return 15;
    case 1:
        return 10;
    case 2:
        return 10;
    case 3:
        return 10;
    case 4:
        return 15;
    default:
        break;
}
return 0;
```

I want to know which is better in many way(code line 、running efficiency...)

I like swift's switch-case......

Comment: When the number of options are relatively few, the switch is better.  The if statements are harder to read, and creating an `NSArray` just to see if some value is in the list is a lot of overhead.  If there are dozens or more options, the `NSArray` approach is better, due to readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch case is always better and most efficient in performance, as all conditions are statically assigned at compile time, and no run-time computation is needed.

Well to make code clear, you can also do

```
switch (section) {
    case 0:
    case 4:
        return 15;
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        return 10;
    default:
    return 0;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use switch when i can. The speed optimization can be real, but for small tests i really don't thing it's significant. The real advantage, in my opinion, is that switch must be exhaustive : you have to handle all the possible values, using the `default:` catch.

Also, switch readability was greatly improved with Swift, because you don't have to add the `break` statements to avoid the fall through the next case, and you can group your conditions in the same line :

```
switch (section) {
case 0, 4:
    return 15
case 1...3:
    return 10
default:
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch is better and use case Range as mentioned by @Michaël Azevedo

The moment the compiler hits a switch statement it creates a lookup table with all possible conditions. Whereas in if-else kind of validation, the compiler has to evaluate the condition every time it goes on an if, else if, else..

Answer (score 0):

Use the switch/case. It is more clear what you're doing that way, which makes for more readable code. Besides, you're always catching the default case, which makes for a deterministic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

switch case is better cause its readable, and as you have created a kind of look up table at compile time ,in switch case. so no calculation and computation are required .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the compiler is better in optimizing a switch-statement than an if-statement.

The compiler doesn't know if the order of evaluating the if-statements is important to you, and can't perform any optimizations there. You could be calling methods in the if-statements, influencing variables. With the switch-statement it knows that all clauses can be evaluated at the same time and can put them in whatever order is most efficient.